# Can you catch an out of memory error in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, caching, memory, mobile

I'm building a mobile web app that will rely on caching. 
If my cache uses to much memory I'm seeing this message in mobile Safari...

> "A problem occurred with this webpage so it was reloaded".

Without intervention the page will reload and do the same thing over again a few times until it gives up.

Are there events I can capture, heap information I can monitor or settings that I can change to build a caching system that is more resilient than forcing page reloads?

Chrome has `window.performace.memory` but I can't seem to find anything related to solving my issue in mobile Safari. Try/catch statements and onBeforeUnload events don't prevent the page loads or provide an opportunity to clear/reduce the cache.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help ?

[Error handling "Out of Memory Exception" in browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25903625/error-handling-out-of-memory-exception-in-browser)

```
var localStorageSpace = function(){
var allStrings = '';
for(var key in window.localStorage){
    if(window.localStorage.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        allStrings += window.localStorage[key];
    }
}
return allStrings ? 3 + ((allStrings.length*16)/(8*1024)) + ' KB' : 'Empty (0 KB)';
};

var storageIsFull = function () {
var size = localStorageSpace(); // old size

// try to add data
var er;
try {
     window.localStorage.setItem("test-size", "1");
} catch(er) {}

// check if data added
var isFull = (size === localStorageSpace());
window.localStorage.removeItem("test-size");

return isFull;
```

}

Comment: I'm not using localStorage, but your proposed system relies on knowing the memory limitations of this feature, I don't know how much memory there is available which is the heart of the problem.

Comment: Another helpfull link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506064/how-do-you-detect-memory-limits-in-javascript